# Geometry nodes use the Incoming vector

Tags: geometry-nodes, shader-nodes

I am trying to build a basic Phong Specular system in geometry nodes, so it can be manually controlled with an empty and affect the geometry.
for specular calculations, i need access to the "Incoming" Vector, which is available in the "Geometry" Shader node. But i am in geometry nodes.
Does anyone know how to get something very similar looking to the Incoming vector in geo nodes? it's ok if the effect only works from the camera point of view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implementation of "incoming" for the camera, try this:

[image]

Comment: Just to make it clear, the 4 leftmost nodes: *Object Info*, *Position*, *Subtract* and *Normalize* make up the implementation of the *Incoming*. The rest is the usage of it. (somewhat obvious, because the dot product produces a scalar, and *Incoming* is a vector).